# How to find out which public key bitbucket uses when pushing?

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket

I'm having a problem when pushing to a bitbucket repository, I'm getting this message:

```
    Pushing to ssh://git@bitbucket.org/banana/pera.git
    Permission denied (publickey).
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
    Pushing to ssh://git@bitbucket.org/banana/pera.git
    Permission denied (publickey).
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
    Pushing to ssh://git@bitbucket.org/banana/pera.git
    Permission denied (publickey).
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
    Pushing to ssh://git@bitbucket.org/banana/pera.git
    Permission denied (publickey).
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
```

Reading some answers here and at Atlassian's forum I saw that to test if my key is OK I should use: `ssh -T hg@bitbucket.org`. I did and I'm getting `Permission denied (publickey).`

My problem now is to know which file it uses so I can give it the proper permissions. How do I do that? All the files under `~/.ssh/` have the 700 permission. I'm using a Macbook.

Thanks for any help

Comment: If you add `-v` to the ssh command, it should show you the key files it attempts to use.

Comment: @DanLowe Thanks you. I can see the file the command tries. The file exists. Do you know if 700 is the right permission? I saw this in their forums but it seems not to work

Comment: The file permission is not the problem, it's the remote end that is complaining about something. If it was a file permission issue, your local ssh client would complain about it and not even try to connect. Mode 700 or 600 for key files should both be fine.

Comment: Probably what you need to do is just compare the key you have (now that you see which one it is) to the keys on your bitbucket account, and make sure there is a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest is to use the `ssh-agent`.

Use `ssh-add` or `ssh-add $privatekey` to add your key to the agent.

Use `ssh-add -L` to print the public key and check that it is the same as the one on bitbucket.

Now try `ssh` or `git clone` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks @michas ! That was the problem, your answer solved the issue